# Fail insert into Impala table WRITE access at least one HDFS path

Tags: insert, impala

Im trying to insert into Impala table.....

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Unable to INSERT into target table (log_wf) because Impala does not have WRITE access to at least one HDFS path: hdfs://Server:8020/desarrollo/data/des/log/log_wf

Comment: Solved: hdfs dfs chown -R impala:yourgroup hdfs://Server:8020/desarrollo/data/des/log/log_wf

Answer (score 7):

In Shell

```
hdfs dfs chown -R impala:yourgroup hdfs://Server:8020/desarrollo/data/des/log/log_wf
```

In Impala

```
invalidate metadata yourdb.yourtable
```

Comment: Care to explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue sent to me by a user of the platform. There was much head scratching as they did have access to the directory and the user impala ran under also had access. Then I noticed they were overwriting the table they were selecting from. For some reason this used to work but has stopped working after a patch.